# how to use phone gap plugin with cordova 2.6?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i want to use the following plugin in my project **cordova-2.6.0** , but the problem i get error telling me plugin not found or its not CDVpluhgin .

i have done the folliwng steps:

1- copying both files SaveToPhotoAlbum.h + SaveToPhotoAlbum.m to plugins folder
2- copying js folder + plugins folder to www folder 
3- setting refrence for both SaveToPhotoAlbum.js and Cordova.2.6.js folder in my html page.
4- the link for plugin is 
https://github.com/grnadav/SaveToPhotoAlbumPhonegapPlugin

and this is my config.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />

    <content src="index.html" />

    <plugins>
        <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
        <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
        <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
        <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
        <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
        <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
        <plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />
        <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
        <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
        <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
        <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
        <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
        <plugin name="SaveToPhotoAlbum" value="SaveToPhotoAlbum" />
    </plugins>

    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

`

https://github.com/grnadav/SaveToPhotoAlbumPhonegapPlugin

Comment: Are you building using Phonegap Build or Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Xcode project, make sure you've added the source files (.m and .h) as resources. You can do this by dragging them from a Finder window and dropping them onto the "plugins" folder in Xcode.
It doesn't matter that the files are actually already in the "plugins" folder - XCode cannot discover this so needs to be told explicitly they are resources by adding them as described.

Answer (score 0):

In my Xcode project,i have added the source files (.m and .h)